# How to use Jquery to address individual posts in Wordpress

Tags: jquery

I'm currently designing a wordpress theme, and I require a bit of javascript for a hover effect. I'm using Wordpress Jquery + Jquery Color Animations plugin.

**The Structure:**

I use a div (class="post") as a container for the wordpress post, and within the "post" div, I have a span (class="title") which I use to display the title of the post.

**What I want to do is:**

1. when the user hovers over "post" div:

   *".title" spans's background color fades from black to red.*
2. when the user hovers out (OnMouserOut) "post" div:

   *".title" spans's background color fades back to black.*

**The Code**

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j(".posts").hover(function(){
    $j (".posts .title").animate({ backgroundColor: "#FF0062" }, 300);
    },function(){
    $j(".posts .title").animate({ backgroundColor: "#231F20" }, 300);
    });
    });
```

**The Problem**

The code works, except when the user hovers over any "post" div, all "title" span change color. So my question is, how do I target the code to address ONLY the "title" span in the "post" div that is in hover state?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers,

Drew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the "title" `span` element that is a descendant of the currently hovered "post":

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
  $j(".posts").hover(function(){
    $j(".title", this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#FF0062" }, 300);
    // or $j(this).find(".title")
  },function(){
    $j(".title", this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#231F20" }, 300);
  });
});
```

The `this` keyword inside the two even handler functions, refer to the currently hovered "post" element.

I use the `context` argument of the [jQuery function](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery), which is exactly the same as using the [Traversing/find](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find) method.